# Reading from a resorce file

Tags: android

[image]

Hi! Here is an image of my project. What I am trying to do here is to read from dictionary_zip_code.json file. You have the method that I am using in the picture.

The problem is that the result of the function is null. Can someone help me with this tank?

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("dictionary_zip_code.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

And here is where i get the null pointer exception:

```
try {
        String text = loadJSONFromAsset(this); // text turns out to be null
        Log.e(TAG , text+"");
        object = new JSONObject(text); // here is where i get the npe.
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You didn't get any stackerror?

Comment: try to post code as it is, not as screenshot

Comment: place the file inside `app/src/main/assets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to copy your json file into assets folder instead of java package.

**Note : If you do not have assets folder then you need to create into your project.**

[image]

Comment: you have to create assets directory

Comment: yes you need to right click and add directory with name of assets

Comment: no body here for spoon feeding so you need to search something for yourself .